# how to create a cylinder chart asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, data-visualization, asp.net-charts

I m drawing a cylinder chart in excel with below data,

[image]

[image]

Is  there any way to draw the same with .net chart control. please suggest?
can we convert excel to some format to produce chart control code?
how to bind data with such controls? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to display a 3D chart by setting property values at design time you need to work with the ChartArea property of the chart control.

The **ChartArea properties** window can be displayed by clicking ChartArea collection in Chart1 properties. In the ChartArea properties window you need to set the **Enable3D property** to True as shown in the next figure

**Referenced article:** http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Microsoft-Chart-with-ASP-NET-35-Part2.aspx